# Make partial view like in web-forms

Tags: partial-views, webforms

I want to add few lines of identical html code to several pages in my web-forms site.
In MVC I know that theres Partial Views that all you have to do is Html.Partial("partial view location"). I dont want to using MVC classes or something like that in my web-forms pages..

And I wonder if theres something like that in web-forms..?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) will take care of this. its small reusable pieces of code

Comment: Yes, but user controls cannot be rendered without a masterpage... for instance returned as a AJAX response to update a container.. I think? That is what I'm looking for.